# R - How to draw 2 box plots on one axis in R?

Tags: statistics, programming

I have two data sets and for each I am able to produce a box plot separately.

However I need to put both these box plots together on a single axis. How do I do this?

Comment: $\texttt{boxplot(X,Y,...)}$ should do the job. However, this is not the right place to ask questions like this, for programming questions you are better served at [Stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Right, this works.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the perfect place to ask this question, but perhaps the the
following method will suffice for making
a nice-looking pair of boxplots on the same axis.

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = rnorm(15, 100, 15);  x2 = rnorm(20, 110, 15)
x = c(x1, x2);  gp = c(rep(1,15), rep(2,20))
boxplot(x ~ gp, col=c("skyblue2","green2"), pch=19)
```

[image]

Or using group names:

```
gp = c(rep("Blue", 15),rep("Green",20))
boxplot(x ~ gp, col=c("skyblue2","green2"), pch=19, main="Widgets")
```

[image]